# How can I avoid hard-coded database credentials on config in my PHP app running into Docker Container

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sdk, configuration-files

**Background**

- I have a Web App running into a PHP Docker Container
- I need to run locally (in a container), in the Jenkin (container - test env), in the Staging (aws-beanstalk) and Production
  (aws-beanstalk)
- And each one of that env, it needs to point to different DB
- I have been trying to solve it using AWS-KMS, AWS-STS, AWS-AMS but could not resolve it properly.

**Requirement**

- I don't want to hardcode DB credentials - security reason

> Any expert suggestion ?

Comment: How about setting environment variables. I think it's possible on beanstalk too

Comment: Generate random password? Not sure what it is ur looking for exactly.

Comment: Depends on environment replace configuration file, You can do this while running containers or in your php config file use if and else condition and pass environment variable (local, staging or production) to read db configuration details.

Comment: In the public place; I don't want to send hardcoded DB credentials - that is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Best practices with AWS is to use AWS Secrets Manager [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html)

Store your database credentials in Secrets Manager. There are lots of coding examples on the Internet.

Then create a service role with permissions to access Secrets Manager. On startup, obtain your credentials from Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret/)! which will manage all secret information required for the container

Comment: It does not fit for this propose, mate.